# Advance function produces segmentation fault in program

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, abstract-data-type

Hi am trying to create a generic list iterator that stores elements of integer or string.I am trying to test a case where it calls the `IteratorG advance(IteratorG it, int n)` function which takes in the list `it` and if `n` is a positive integer,it advances(moves) towards the first element by n times.If n is negative,it advances towards the last element in the list by n times.The elements are then copied to a newly created list `lis` and the list returned.If advancing by n times is not possible,the function returns NULL.

For example,suppose theres an array list `[ 20 12 15 5 14 10 5 9 3 ]` and its pointing to 14.when `advance(list,4)` is called,it moves to 20 and returns list as `[5 15 12 20]`.

This is the consise function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "iteratorG.h"

typedef struct Node {

  void *value;  // value of thee list item
  struct Node *prev;
  // pointer previous node in list
  struct Node *next;
  // pointer to next node in list

  // implemented struct here .. 
} Node;

typedef struct IteratorGRep {

  int  numofit;      // count of items in list
  Node *head;         // first node in list
  Node *curr;       // current node in list
  Node *tail;       // last node in list

  ElmCompareFp  cmpElm;
  ElmNewFp  newElm;
  ElmFreeFp freeElm;

  // implemented struct here .. 

} IteratorGRep;

IteratorG newIterator(ElmCompareFp cmpFp, ElmNewFp newFp, ElmFreeFp freeFp){

  IteratorG newit;


  if ((newit = malloc(sizeof (struct IteratorGRep)))==NULL)
  {
    printf("Error...! \n");

  }

  //assert (newit != NULL);
  newit->numofit = 0;
  newit->head = NULL;
  newit->tail = NULL;
  newit->curr = NULL;
  newit->cmpElm=cmpFp;
  newit->newElm=newFp;
  newit->freeElm=freeFp;
  return newit;

  // implemented function here and changed return value 
}

IteratorG advance(IteratorG it, int n){

  int zero;
  zero=0;

  IteratorG lis;
  lis = malloc(sizeof (struct IteratorGRep));
  assert (lis != NULL);
  lis->numofit = 0;
  lis->head = NULL;
  lis->tail = NULL;
  lis->curr = NULL;

  Node *tem;
  if ((tem = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL) { 
    return 0;
  }  

  if(n<0 && distanceFromStart(it)!=0 )

  { 
  for(tem=it->curr;n!=zero;it->curr=it->curr->prev)
  {
    add(lis,tem);
    zero++;

  }
  return lis;
  }
  if(n>0 && distanceToEnd(it)!=0)
  { 
    for(tem=it->curr;n!=zero;it->curr=it->curr->next)
    {
      add(lis,tem);
      zero++;

    }
    return lis;
  }
  //To be implemented
  //move forward by n times
  return NULL;
}
```

If required,i also created a header file for the code IteratorG.h:

```
#ifndef LISTITERATORG_H
#define LISTITERATORG_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct IteratorGRep *IteratorG;

typedef int   (*ElmCompareFp)(void const *e1, void const *e2);
typedef void *(*ElmNewFp)(void const *e1);
typedef void  (*ElmFreeFp)(void *e1);


IteratorG newIterator(ElmCompareFp cmpFp, ElmNewFp newFp, ElmFreeFp freeFp);
int  add(IteratorG it, void *vp);

IteratorG advance(IteratorG it, int n);

#endif
```

Theres also a int compare file that process integer data types.This is its header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void  positiveIntFree(void *vp);
void *positiveIntNew(void const *vp);
int   positiveIntCompare(void const *vp1, void const *vp2);
```

This is the code for it:

```
     #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include "positiveIntType.h" 

/* =====   Functions for positiveIntType  ===== */

    void positiveIntFree(void *vp){
      free(vp);
    }

    void *positiveIntNew(void const *vp){
      int v = * (int *) vp ;   

      int *ip = malloc(sizeof(int));
      *ip = v;
      return ip;
    }

      int positiveIntCompare(void const *vp1, void const *vp2){
      int v1 = * (int *) vp1 ;
      int v2 = * (int *) vp2 ;

      if( v1 == v2 ){ return 0; }
      if( v1 < v2 ) { return -1; }
      return 1;
    }
```

I am using a Linux environment and the errors are indicative from the results. I tried using gdb to diagnose the problem and am able to narrow down the issue to the following line in the advance function:

```
add(lis,tem);
```

There shouldnt be any issue with the add function which adds pointers to the list below because it has been tested and works fine.I will just include it here:

```
int  add(IteratorG it, void *vp){

  Node *temp;
  if ((temp = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL) { 
    return 0; 
  }
  Node *tempe;
  if ((temp = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL) { 
    return 0; 
  }

  temp->value = it->newElm(vp);
  //temp->next=NULL;

  if(it->curr==NULL)
  {
    //temp->next=it->curr;
    it->head=it->tail=temp;
    it->curr=temp;
  }
  else
  {
   tempe=it->curr;
   tempe->prev=temp;
    temp->next=tempe;
    it->curr=tempe;
    it->curr=temp;
    it->head=temp;


  } 

    //it->tail=it->head=it->curr;
    return 1;
  }
```

Now the rest of the code works.Its just the interaction between the two functions that is giving problems.Heres a test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "iteratorG.h"
#include "positiveIntType.h"

#define MAXARRAY 5


void prnInt(void *vp){
  assert(vp != NULL);
  printf(" %d", *((int *) vp) );    
}

void prnIt(IteratorG it, void (*fp) (void *p) ){
  int count = 0;
  while(hasNext(it)){
    void *nextP = next(it); 
    count++;
    if(count > 1) { printf(", "); }
    fp(nextP);      
  }
  printf("\n"); 
}

void test3(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-03       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it1 = newIterator(positiveIntCompare, positiveIntNew, positiveIntFree);
  int a[MAXARRAY] = { 04, 54, 15, 12, 34};
  for(int i=0; i<MAXARRAY; i++){
    int result = add(it1 , &a[i]); 
    printf("> Inserting %d: %s \n", a[i], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  reset(it1);
  printf("> it1 (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it1, prnInt);
  reset(it1);

  IteratorG advIt1 = advance(it1, 4);
  printf("> advance(it1, 4) returns: \n");
  prnIt(advIt1, prnInt);


  printf("--====  End of Test-03 ====------\n");
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  test3();


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

EDIT:Added in header files for the respective codes for compilation and testing.

Comment: You need to prepare a [mcve].

Comment: `it->curr=tempe; it->curr=temp;` looks like a typo

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the feedback.I have added the necessary example.

Comment: @VTT r u referring to the add function?If so i kinda created two nodes to process the function.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], not an "example". For example, I can't even compile your code because `IteratorG` is undefined.

Comment: "There shouldnt be any issue with the add function (...) because it has been tested and works fine" And did you test it with parameters being null? How did that work out?

Comment: @melpomene hi there.I have added more example files here.thanks!

Comment: This is far from minimal. Is all that code really needed just to reproduce the problem? And it's still not even complete (e.g. no `main` function).

Comment: @RuudHelderman It returns an assertion NULL which aborts the program(which is suppose to happen)

Comment: @melpomene actually the main function is in the test case below (which i included).It kinda functions as the main tester of the function

Comment: @melpomene i kinda edited out some functions to keep the program concise.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Please.

Comment: @lemonsss The assert is useful but offers no guarantees; it is not uncommon in [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) scenarios for a pointer to be clobbered later on. Do not assume that `add` is being called with valid parameters. And keep in mind that garbage pointers are harder to assert than null pointers. Same for valid pointers to invalidated memory.

Comment: @melpomene hi there i have added it to reproduce the program.let me know if it works.The issue seems to be at the advance function.(i have read through the MCV example and understand that the program needs to be able to reproduce in order to have clearer view of the problem).

Comment: `iteratorG.h` seems to be missing. Also, **the M in MCVE stands for Minimal**. This code is not minimal by any means. You should have created a single file demonstrating the problem in (hopefully) less than 50 lines.

Comment: @melpomene `iteratorG.h` is actually included in there.And for the minimal part wouldnt the files require the header program also?

Comment: @melpomene the code should probably work but am not too sure where the problem actually lies in.

Comment: @RuudHelderman i tested out the add function by itself with the test code and it seems to work.Am not sure if both the advance and the add function are working properly.

Comment: I dont suppose i need to pass in a void pointer to the add function so that it works.Ive tried to pass in a normal pointer and it dosent work either.

Comment: `add` is called sometimes with an `int *`, sometimes with a `Node *` as second parameter. The compiler says fine because of those `void *` all over the place. Please refactor: remove __all__ type casts, then fix the resulting type mismatches by replacing `void *` by the correct strong types. Type mismatch errors are _not_ a nuisance; they are there to __help you prevent UB and segfaults!__

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in case people of the future need help:

Calling this in the advance function helps to initialise the list with the function parameters that creates the list.The function elements,importantly,need to be assigned with the function elements that are linked to the list it.

```
IteratorG lis = newIterator(it->cmpElm,it->newElm,it->freeElm);
```

thanks.